# Nautilus-actions-new equivalent FileManager-Actions?

Tags: nautilus

Is there a nautilus-actions-new equivalent for filemanager-actions, in order to create a new action from a command line ?

Nautilus-actions-new command returns command not found.

Nothing appears in the documentation on this subject (Help/Content...).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent command for nautilus-actions-new is:

```
/usr/libexec/filemanager-actions/fma-new
```